# javascript increment name of variable

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, increment

I get an object with partial results of match from database.

```
[Object { home1=4, away1=3, home2=4, away2=5, home3=6, away3=7, home4=6, away4=5, home5=3, away5=6}]
```

home1 it's a result of first part of home team,
away1 -> away team, home2 it's a result of second part of home team... etc etc

data in my case is each row, which i get from database. 
In rows i have td with class: home1, home2, home3, away1, away2 and there are values of corresponding part of match.
I want to check if value is equal to what I got from database. 
Something like this

```
if ($('.home1') === data[index].home1;
if($('.away2') === data[index].away2;
```

there should be some loop. I have no idea how to do this, I thought about an array

```
var array = [

                        {
                             home1: data[index].home1,
                             away1: data[index].away1
                        },
                          {
                             home2: data[index].home2,
                             away2: data[index].away2
                        },
                          {
                             home3: data[index].home3,
                             away3: data[index].away3
                        },
                         {
                             home4: data[index].home4,
                             away4: data[index].away4
                        },
                         {
                             home5: data[index].home5,
                             away5: data[index].away5
                        }


                    ]
```

and then for loop:

```
for(var X=0; X<5;X++){
homeX == data[index].homeX 
}
```

How can I increment name of variable by eval function? or is there any other solution? I'm very confused.

Comment: $(.home1) is invalid selector

Comment: you should get properly formatted JSON from database. + you should post your code to get some help.

Answer (score 1):

You can access object properties using operator []:

```
for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++)
{
    var item = array[i];
    var homePropertyName = 'home' + (i+1);
    //now you can access homeX property of item using item[homePropertyName]
    //e.g. item[homePropertyName] = data[index][homePropertyName]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use a little different structure which might fit your needs better, like this:

```
array = [
    0: array [
        "home": "Text for home",
        "away": "Text for away"
    ],

    1: array [
        "home": "",
        "away": ""
    ]
    // More sub-arrays here
];
```

You can also initialize it with a for loop:

```
var array = new Array();
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    array[i] = [
         "home": "",
         "away": ""
    ];
}
```

Or like this:

```
array[0]["home"] = "Text for home";
array[0]["away"] = "Text for away";
```

You can use this structure for the data-array also, and then use a for-loop to go through them both (like if you wish to find an element):

```
var result = NULL;
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (    (array[i]["home"] == data[index]["home"]) &&
            (array[i]["away"] == data[index]["away"])
    ) {
        // Found matching home and away
        result = array[i];
        break;
    }
}
if (result != NULL) {
    alert("Found match: " + result["home"] + " - " + result["away"]);
}
else {
    alert("No match");
}
```

PS: Code is not tested, let me know if something is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you can access global properties in browser via window object like this ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yEK3K/1/)):

```
value1 = "ONE";

alert( window['value'+1] );
```

But it is not good design. You should look into how to properly format JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

I have something like this:

```
for(var i=0; i<2; i++)

{

    var item = ARR[i];

    for(var x=0;x<5;x++){

    var hPropertyName = 'home_p' + (x+1);

    var aPropertyName = 'away_p' + (x+1);

     item[hPropertyName] = ARR[i][hPropertyName];    

      item[aPropertyName] = ARR[i][aPropertyName];

}
```

and it works when i create an array:

```
 var ARR = [

        {

            home_p1: 4,

            away_p1: 5,

            home_p2: 8,

            away_p2: 9,

            home_p3: 2,

            away_p3: 1,

            home_p4: 5,

            away_p4: 3,

            home_p5: 3,

            away_p5: 2

        },

        {

             home_p1: 6,

            away_p1: 1,

            home_p2: 1,

            away_p2: 2,

            home_p3: 3,

            away_p3: 4,

            home_p4: 5,

            away_p4: 6,

            home_p5: 3,

            away_p5: 2

        }

    ];
```

but I don't have to create an array, because i have to work on object which I get from database :

```
[Object { event_id=19328, home_result=3, away_result=2, home_p1=4, away_p1=3, home_p2=1, away_p2=2 ...... }]
```

I'm  only interested in these parameters --> home_p , away_p
I want to push it to my array to looks like ARR. I think i should convert an object which I get to an array

Answer (score 0):

If you are using string name for your attributes then you could try using template literals?

```
var someObject = {}

for(let i=0 ; i<values.length ; i++){
    someObject[`home${i+1}`] = values[i];
}
```

and if you need it to be ES5 you could just use string concatenation. Below is a working example:

```js
values = [1,2,3,4,5];

let someObject = {};

for(let i=0 ; i<values.length ; i++){
    someObject[`value${i+1}`]=values[i];
}

console.log(someObject.value1);
console.log(someObject.value2);
console.log(someObject.value3);
console.log(someObject.value4);
console.log(someObject.value5);
```